# ASP.NET session ID value

Tags: asp.net

Relatively simple question regarding the value of session ID - Session ID is tied to a specific instance of the browser, correct (instance meaning window)?  So I start with an empty desktop (WinXP or Win7 or whatever client O/S).  I open an IE browser window and request a web page from an ASP.NET website.  I then open a second IE browser window and request the same web page from the same ASP.NET website.  (1) I assume there will be 2 different session IDs, one for each of the two IE browser windows, correct?  Then, I open an additional tab within one of the IE browser windows.  (2) Will that additional tab have the same session ID as the browser window, or will it have a third unique session ID?  I know I could do a little testing to look at this but I need to answer a boss's question right away LOL - so I figured someone could probably just answer this question off the top of their head.  TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a new tab, they share the same session. If you want new session at the same time, you should open the site in a different browser.

Answer (score 3):

The session cookie is created per browser instance, not per browser window. If you open 3 Internet Explorer windows they will all use the same session ID.

That session ID is kept around for other requests, regardless of whether a request comes from the same window or a different window within the same instance of the browser.

By default, "instance" refers to the browser until all windows are completely closed. This can be extended, but keep in mind that sessions also remain in memory on your server (by default, this can be changed as well) so you could impact performance if you configure sessions to remain alive for too long.